# Passing Values to tickFormatter Function in Recharts BarChart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I am trying to plot Dates in a BarChart, which requires converting timestamps to their respective Unix Epoch values (i.e. seconds since 1/1/1970). This means that any dates prior to 1970 are plotted as **negative** numbers.

My initial thinking was to have a function which first found the earliest date (lowest epoch number), then use this to set a new base for my BarChart. This would effectively ignore 1970 and have dates padded accordingly.

Unfortunately, Recharts' `tickFormatter` property in `<XAxis />` and `<YAxis />` both only seem to accept functions, with `value` being implicitly called when the formatter does its work.

This is something similar to what I'd like to do, then format according to the "lowest number" given to the `removeEpochBuffer` function. This should treat the parameter as the buffer number to strip from the plotted number provided, and then return the original (correct) epoch number that can be reformatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```html
            <YAxis
              name={getYAxisLabel(yAxisFields, CHART_TYPES.COLUMNCHART)}
              domain={['auto', 'auto']}
              tickFormatter={removeEpochBuffer(lowestNumbers[0])}
              allowDataOverflow={false}
            />
```

This is similar to what I have now, based on what I have seen on GitHub :

```html
            <YAxis
              name={getYAxisLabel(yAxisFields, CHART_TYPES.COLUMNCHART)}
              domain={['auto', 'auto']}
              tickFormatter={customFormatter}
              allowDataOverflow={false}
            />
```

Is this even possible with Recharts?

- http://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis
- https://github.com/search?l=JSX&p=3&q=recharts+tickformatter&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

I've been gnawing at this exact same issue for awhile and I figured out a workaround that gets the job done. Mine is a chart that only has a tick on the first trading day of the week, month, whatever. What I did was calculated the array of ticks I wanted before rendering the chart. xAxis looked like so:

[image: X-Axis]

Passing that array as a prop to the tick component means it will show up nested in the props, which will also receive the tick data every time it renders. Good start, but you actually have to render EVERY tick and then filter within , because recharts will only render this based on predetermined ticks. I had to set the interval to zero and manage every tick or it wouldn't work. Couldn't figure out how to hack that calculation.

My tick component is based on the one in the API examples, with an added trick.

[image: Tick Component]

So here it actually renders for every data point, but the text is empty for any date not in your desired array of ticks in the props. I still have to figure out how to adjust the grid so it's not too busy. Will update if I get that to work as well.

Comment: If you decrease opacity of the grid it actually looks ok, especially since the grid is color responsive. You can make the grid almost invisible with the active highlighted.

Comment: The best option so far with the grid is setting a boolean to turn off the vertical grid lines in <CartesianGrid /> props above a certain number of data points. That and the original solution get you a customizable date axis. You can setup the input tick array as whatever you want.